# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 error inflating class com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am building an app and am trying to use Aeris weather Api. I followed the tutorial they provided but am getting the same error. Here is the code

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
        android:id="@+id/aerisfragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView>



</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/MapFrame"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        AerisEngine.initWithKeys(this.getString(R.string.AerisId), this.getString(R.string.AerisKey), this);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //add a fragment
        MapFragment myFragment = new MapFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.MapFrame, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)
    {

    }
}
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
public class MapFragment extends MapViewFragment implements OnAerisMapLongClickListener,OnAerisMarkerInfoWindowClickListener,AerisCallback {
.....
.....
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false); //LINE 112
        mapView = (AerisMapView)view.findViewById(R.id.aerisfragment_map);
        mapView.init(savedInstanceState, AerisMapType.GOOGLE);
        initMap();
//        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
    private void initMap() {
        mapView.moveToLocation(new LatLng(34.7, -86.7), 9);
        mapView.setOnAerisMapLongClickListener(this);
        mapView.setOnAerisWindowClickListener(this);

    }
.....
.....

}
```

I have override all the necessary methods and the project builds with no error but when i run it i get exception. Following is the Stack trace. I have read all the blogs but couldn't find anything. I am new to android and learning still. Thanks

```
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.rohan.weatherapp, PID: 4722
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rohan.weatherapp/com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:112)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:112) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:112) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView.<init>(AerisMapView.java:155)
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rohan.weatherapp.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:112) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-21 19:25:52.010 4722-4722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-21 19:25:52.064 4722-4761/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 4761: swapBuffers(324): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
11-21 19:25:52.064 4722-4761/? A/OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
11-21 19:25:52.064 4722-4761/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4761 (RenderThread)
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rohan.weatherapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Next24Hours"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Next7Days" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Dependencies**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rohan.weatherapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile files('libs/aerismaps-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/aeris-android-lib-1.1.1.jar')
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace?  It is hitting an error creating the Map view, but doesn't say why.  Usually there will be another error message the indicates where the error happened that caused this inflation exception.

Comment: please show us your dependies and Manifest.xml

Comment: I have added both the manifest and dependencies.

Comment: minifyEnabled true => false or add proguard

Comment: use ctrl+b on the com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView to watch whether it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that there is a resource (probably a string) missing, as indicated by the `Resources$NotFoundException` that's being reported in the mapping library.  Have you set your `aeris_client_id` and `aeris_client_secret` properly in the strings.xml file?

It looks like this library is available in Maven Central as an AAR, which includes all of it's resources so you don't have to worry about Jars and dependencies.  I would recommend adding it to your project that way, by following the instructions at the bottom of the [installation instructions](http://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/toolkits/aeris-android-sdk/getting-started/installation/).

You can replace all of that Aeris jar stuff in your `build.gradle` file with this and that's all you need.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.hamweather:aeris-maps-library:1.1.1@aar'
}
```